# Approximate Text compression by training model?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, machine-learning-model

I have a key-value form of dataset. Basically two sets of integers in many-to-one mapping. Like f(123) corresponds to 4652, f(24) corresponds to 12 and so on. Size of this dataset is say around upto 10^7.

This is too large. So my Idea is to train this dataset on some model and store trained model's parameters only, so when I have to answer say f(24), I can pass 24 as input to my model and print model's output. My thinking was overfitting some model on the dataset could possibly result in high accuracy of say greater than 99%. I strictly want size of parameters to be less than 50,000 bytes.

I tried making vanilla neural network but error percentage is way too high.
I found an interesting [blog](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/60825) trying same approach as mine. Kindly let me know if something is unclear to you in comments.

**Concrete Example Problem**
To give you a concrete example of what I am trying. Here is the [DataSet](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hmE8OlN8-pPZdCYd8p0_PtXYV0ddRP4U/view?usp=sharing), ith line stores f(i) in this file. I am trying to make a code which is of 50k bytes and can answer queries f(i). Ofcourse while training there are no limits, but after training it should be a file of 50k length at max.

Comment: If you have dataset of 2 columns, I dont think you can train model to give you meaningfull results, maybe its more logical to solve storage problem? Maybe this will be usefull for you in particular  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33189299/most-efficient-way-to-store-a-large-number-of-key-value-pairs-of-integers-separ

Comment: @YaroslawHomenko Thankyou. I looked into the link, it isn't helpful as I have strict Limit of 50k bytes for storage! Yes I understand it is a very difficult problem but I think someone must have done some progress :)

Comment: @YaroslawHomenko : One important thing clear - I don't need meaningful training.. what I am look is to reproduce dataset with high probability. I don't care if it outputs garbage for an entry not given in dataset! So See this problem as using ML training for compression!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem can be solved with a [hash map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table). If the dataset is very large, you can use an approximate hashmap. Examples of approximate hashmaps are [Bloom Filters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) and [Cuckoo Filters](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dga/papers/cuckoo-conext2014.pdf).

Comment: Hi @Brian Speiring . Approximate hashmaps look good but I am not sure if they are good enough? Isn't bloom filter store only boolean.  Also as I am to submit only 50k of source code, how many numbers can bloom/cuckoo filter squeeze approximately?

Comment: Since Bloom Filter is a type of hashmap, it can store any type of data in the cell of the table.  You can fix the size of Bloom Filter. If you fix the size of the Bloom Filter then your false positive rate will vary (vice versa - Set false positive rate and the size will vary).  Here is a Bloom Filter Calculator to find out how many numbers can be stored https://hur.st/bloomfilter/

Answer (score 1):

This seems like an interesting problem. I haven't encountered such problems before, but however following are my observations:

1. The problem with your approach might be because of the lack of numerical meaning in your numerical data. This happens when your input is for e.g. categorical data with numbers. 
   In such case, try encoding your input data and then pass them to your neural Network.If the dimensionality goes too high, try using PCA.
2. The problem which you're trying to solve is a classic *Hashing* problem. Hence I agree to @Brian Spiering's answer of using approximate Hashmaps.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what you have mentioned in your question is like that you have just one input feature and one output, and your task is regression. The point here is that you have to investigate your data first and find out whether it can be learnt or not. I will explain this later but before that, I have a suggestion about your consideration about separating models. Do not do that if you are not sure each training split has a same distribution as the real data distribution. It seems that you want to do ensemble learning in a wrong way. The main reason that you have not found a good precision is that if you change the distribution of your data, you will have poor performance on the test data. In other words, your model cannot generalise well due to poor training. On the other hand, changing the size of the training data does not reduce the size of your model if they are drawn iid and they are large enough to be learnt.

First, you have to find the Bayes error of your training data. Because you have just one input feature, you may have high Bayes error, which in your case means your inputs and outputs do not satisfy the functionality condition, for each specific input you should just have one output. You have to investigate whether for each input there is just a single output or not. If you find out that you have a large Bayes error, you can be sure that you cannot have a good performance. On the contrary, if you see that you have low Bayes error, then you can employ linear and non-linear models.

My solution is that, try to solve your problem using a two-layer neural network, find the correct architecture that can generalise well first, then, after finding a good model check the size of the network. Another solution can be using non-linear `SVM` if you are sure that your data is non-linear, although I guess a two-layer network can solve your problem if you don't have high Bayes error.

Comment: Hi @Media , I think you are getting the question wrong. I am having poor training accuracy with neural net. There is no other separate 'test data'!

Comment: @MaggiIggam don't you want to generalise them? If you are getting low accuracy, first bring your network architecture. Then, please do the first thing that I've mentioned. You may have high Bayes error.

Comment: My training data = test data. All i want is to make parameter small enough to keep parameters within 50k bytes. Do you get what i am trying to do?

Comment: Yes, did you do what I said? I guess you may have not figured it out. lets say you have input 10 and for that 10 there are two outcomes, one 151, and one 5. In this case, no machine learning algorithm can learn it in the current feature space. Did you get it?

Comment: @MaggiIggam If you have difficulty in doing that, try to make a histogram, it will give you exactly what you need, the distribution of your sample.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a relation between *x* and *f(x)* then surely you can get some meaningful results, especially when you can settle for something less than 100%.

Alternatively consider an extra-tight compression also, like PAQ8HP12 with some pre-processing of the data to make it compressible better.

Sorry couldn't open your dataset.